# Elixir + Amnesia: How to read an attribute?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to use this hex package: https://github.com/meh/amnesia

Here's my schema:

```
use Amnesia
require Logger
require IEx
defdatabase Database do
  deftable User, [{ :id, autoincrement }, :device_identifier, :match_history], type: :ordered_set, indices: [:device_identifier] do
    @type t :: %User{ id: non_neg_integer, device_identifier: String.t, match_history: List.t }

    ...
  end
end
```

and here's where the error happens:

```
Amnesia.transaction do
  // IEx.pry
  queue = User.where(:device_identifier != device_identifier)
  if queue do
    Logger.info "dequeuing another user"
    matched_user = List.first(queue.values)
    matched_user |> User.delete
    push socket, "match_found", %{ device_identifier: matched_user.device_identifier } 
  else
    Logger.info "queuing user"
    push socket, "queued", %{}
  end
end
```

When I try to call `matched_user.device_identifier`, it fails. But isn't this an attribute on the model? In the README in the github repo, it calls `content` on the Message model, so why can't I do the same with `device_identifier` on my User model?

I even tried it with the `id` field:

```
pry(8)> matched_user.id
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Database.User.id/1 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

      * id/0
```

Is there a way to find out what methods my matched_user object responds to?

Comment: Can you try printing the value of `matched_user` before you execute `matched_user.id`?

Comment: @Dogbert yeh I get this: `{Database.User, 2, "5pyia9cej4", nil}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amnesia by default returns a tuple for each matching entry instead of the appropriate struct, for example, in your case it returned `{Database.User, 2, "5pyia9cej4", nil}`. To get structs back from the raw query results, Amnesia provides a convenient function `Amnesia.Selection.values/1`. The following change should work:

Replace

```
matched_user = List.first(queue.values)
```

with

```
matched_user = List.first(Amnesia.Selection.values(queue))
```

You might also want to use pattern matching here to make the code more idiomatic:

```
[matched_user | _] = Amnesia.Selection.values(queue)
```

Comment: do you know how I would `update` an existing record? I can't find any docs on any of this...

Comment: I found `Amnesia.Selection.values` in the tests: https://github.com/meh/amnesia/blob/211d98275c085a9e3049ccb8db8d29f76b3ffbfc/test/amnesia/database_test.exs#L56.

Answer (score 0):

@Edmund about your question in the comment on how to update an existing record. Could not format the code inside a comment so I posted an answer. Just fell on to it. Here is a small func that it seems to do the trick on how to update a record. First you must select the records you need to update. I am completely new to Elixir but I think it is no so bad:

```
def update_value(entity_id) do
  Amnesia.transaction do
    entity = Entity.where entity_key == entity_id
  end
  |> Amnesia.Selection.values
  |> Enum.each(fn e ->
    Amnesia.transaction do
      %Entity{e | status: :started} |>
      Entity.write()
    end
  end) 
end
```

Comment: It's only works if the database type is `set`. If the database is a `bag`, a new record is created